# Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud edition: How to set product as new?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1-ece

I am working on a Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud Edition project and stuck in a big problem.

I want to show some products in the list of new products in the home page, but I am not able to set product as new.

I found that there is a checkbox named as **Set Product as New**, but when I check that checkbox and save product, the value of the checkbox is not getting saved.

Please see attached screenshot for reference:

[image: Product field is not being saved]

Is this a bug in Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud Edition or am I missing something?

In Magento 2 community edition, there are 2 fields (namely **Set Product as New From** and **Set Product as New To**) to set the product as new, but in Magento 2 ECE, I could not find such fields.

Please guide me how can I set the product as new?

Comment: Have you got any solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **This seems to happen only in Magento 2.1 E.E**.

Go to ***Products > Catalog*** and select the products you want to edit. Then click the ***Actions*** list and select **Update attributes** option. There you will find the **Set As New Product fields** as in Magento 2 C.E

[image]